# After RoboFramework finishes the test execution sets the output folder to read-only

Tags: windows, permissions, iis-7.5, robotframework, folder-permissions

I want the RF report to be output in IIS folder at the end of every script execution but as soon as this happens the IIS folder is reverted to read-only meaning the next time the execution tries to output a report its mangling the results.

I have changed permission on the IIS folders, restarted machine etc. Granted permissions on application pools but the folder always reverts to read-only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by multiple instances of iedriverserver.exe not being shut down on browser close.